# Optimize Postgres query involving multiple functions, dynamic sql, and polymorphism

Tags: postgresql

[EDIT]: A large amount of the time seems to be pgAdmin rendering. Without pgAdmin in the mix, this takes 40 seconds. I would still be interested in optimization suggestions.

Postgres Version: PostgreSQL 10.17

**My queries are working correctly, but are slow.**

Background:
I have a database with tables containing different versions of similar data, each about 150 columns. The database also contains versions of aging factors, which contain multipliers for some, but not all of the data fields. I need to return aged data.

The aging tables have a year, state code, and factor for each field. Aging is cumulative by state code across years, so if aging from 2015 to 2020, the final aging factor for Field A in Alabama is (2015 AL A) * (2016 AL A) * (2017 AL A) * (2018 AL A) * (2019 AL A) * (2020 AL A). I have written a custom aggregate function (MUL) that does the multiplications. In most cases, there is a single aging factor for those fields that have aging. In some cases, there are different aging factors based on whether the value is positive or negative.

To get the aged data, I call a custom function (get_aged_data) with the begin year, end year, aging version, and data version. This function determines which fields have aging factors and assembles dynamic SQL matching the versions. This function joins using the state code field to the results from the function that calculates the aging factors (get_aging_factors) and does the multiplications to return the final results. The data tables have an index on the state code field.

All of this works correctly, but takes [edit: 40 seconds] to return 760,000 records. The function calls are making it difficult to use Explain/Analyze to find the bottlenecks. Any suggestions for speeding this up?

Example call

```
SELECT * FROM my_schema.get_aged_data('2015', '2019', 'datamod_aging_20181001', 'data_2013_20150101', NULL::my_schema.data_2013_20150101);
```

FUNCTION - get_aged_data

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION my_schema.get_aged_data(
    begin_year character varying,
    end_year character varying,
    aging_version character varying,
    data_version character varying,
    _tbl_type anyelement)
    RETURNS SETOF anyelement 
    LANGUAGE 'plpgsql'
    COST 100
    VOLATILE 
    ROWS 1e+06
AS $BODY$
DECLARE my_sql varchar;
DECLARE aging_list varchar[];
BEGIN
    SELECT ARRAY_AGG(column_name::varchar ORDER BY column_name) INTO aging_list FROM information_schema.columns WHERE data_type='numeric' AND table_schema='my_schema' AND table_name=aging_version;
    my_sql = CONCAT(
    'SELECT ',
    (
        SELECT 
            STRING_AGG(CONCAT(
                '(',
                CASE 
                    WHEN s.column_name = ANY(aging_list) THEN CONCAT('d.', s.column_name, ' * a.', s.column_name)
                    WHEN CONCAT(s.column_name, 'pos') = ANY(aging_list) THEN CONCAT(
                        'CASE ',
                        'WHEN d.', s.column_name, ' < 0 THEN d.', s.column_name, ' * a.', s.column_name, 'neg',
                        ' ELSE d.', s.column_name, ' * a.', s.column_name, 'pos',
                        ' END'
                    )
                    ELSE CONCAT('d.', s.column_name)
                END,
                ')',
                CASE
                    WHEN s.data_type = 'numeric' THEN CONCAT('::numeric(', s.numeric_precision, ',', s.numeric_scale, ')')
                    ELSE CONCAT('::', s.data_type)
                END,
                ' AS ', 
                s.column_name),
            ', ')
        FROM (SELECT column_name, udt_name::regtype::varchar as data_type, numeric_precision, numeric_scale FROM information_schema.columns WHERE table_schema='my_schema' AND table_name=data_version) s
    ),
    ' FROM my_schema.', 
    data_version,
    ' d INNER JOIN my_schema.get_aging_factors(''',
    begin_year,
    ''', ''',
    end_year,
    ''', ''',
    aging_version,
    ''', NULL::my_schema.', 
    aging_version,
    ') a ON a.state = d.xstate',
    ' ORDER BY d.recid'
);

    RETURN QUERY EXECUTE format(my_sql, pg_typeof(_tbl_type));
    RETURN;
END
$BODY$;
```

FUNCTION get_aging_factors

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION my_schema.get_aging_factors(
    begin_year character varying,
    end_year character varying,
    aging_version character varying,
    _tbl_type anyelement)
    RETURNS SETOF anyelement 
    LANGUAGE 'plpgsql'
    COST 100
    VOLATILE 
    ROWS 100
AS $BODY$
DECLARE my_sql varchar;
BEGIN
    my_sql = CONCAT(
    'SELECT MIN(fromyear), MAX(toyear), state, ',
    (SELECT STRING_AGG(CONCAT(
        'MUL(', 
        s.column_name, 
        ')::numeric(', s.numeric_precision, ',', s.numeric_scale, ') AS ', 
        s.column_name), 
    ', ')
    FROM (SELECT column_name, numeric_precision, numeric_scale FROM information_schema.columns WHERE data_type='numeric' AND table_schema='my_schema' AND table_name=aging_version) s
    ),
    ' FROM my_schema.', 
    aging_version,
    ' WHERE fromyear BETWEEN ',
    begin_year,
    ' AND ',
    end_year,
    ' GROUP BY state ORDER BY state'
);
    RETURN QUERY EXECUTE format(my_sql, pg_typeof(_tbl_type));
    RETURN;
END
$BODY$;
```

[EXPLAIN ANALYZE OUTPUT from get_aging_factors](https://explain.depesz.com/s/CmHF)

[EXPLAIN ANALYZE OUTPUT from get_aged_data](https://explain.depesz.com/s/srIK)

Comment: What is the `EXPLAIN` statement you are using? Also post the `EXPLAIN` output here or if it is really long here [explain.depesz](https://explain.depesz.com/)

Comment: EXPLAIN SELECT * FROM my_schema.get_aged_data('2015', '2019', 'datamod_aging_20181001', 'data_2013_20150101', NULL::my_schema.data_2013_20150101);

Output: 
Function Scan on get_aged_data  (cost=0.25..10000.25 rows=1000000 width=1523)

Comment: I would try with `explain (analyze, verbose, buffers)` and post the result as update to your question. If that does not show anything useful, then run the query in `get_aged_data()` outside the function with same `EXPLAIN` settings. Then the same with query in `get_aging_factors`.

Comment: EXPLAIN/ANALYZE outputs added @AdrianKlaver

Comment: Could you change the output to not be `FORMAT JSON`, it makes it easier to read and allows me to throw it on [explain.depesz](https://explain.depesz.com/).

Comment: @AdrianKlaver: EXPLAIN output changed to explain.depesz links

Comment: Hmm the `EXPLAIN` shows the query taking ~27 secs. In what client are you running it now? The slow part seems to be a hash join on d.xstate = a.state. I honestly have not worked my way through the built query to figure out what that represents. What are those fields and are they indexed?

Comment: The xstate and recid fields in the base data table are indexed. The joined table is being returned from a function and is not indexed, though it is only about 50 rows. The time difference is probably due to removing the time it takes to assemble the queries inside the function call. I outputted the assembled query and ran EXPLAIN ANALYZE on that.

Comment: The only thing I can think of at the moment is to take the results of the query from `get_aging_factors()` and put them in a temporary table and use that in the join instead of the function with and without an index on `state` and see what happens? Another option would be to do that as a CTE.

Comment: Temp table with index definitely helped. Took it down by about 37%.

Comment: Yeah the stuff happening in the function is opaque to the planner, it needs to 'see' the data to come up with a good plan.